# Android Studio - missing properties

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

Created a game, now implementing Google Play Services. I have imported as module the BaseGameUtils library. But now in BaseGameActivity, BaseGameUtils, 
GameHelper and GameHelperUtils there is missing alot of files. "CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL" for every other thing implemented in that library.

I tried to do the build path. But if I right click on a project there is no properties. I tried every possible thing. Cannot open the properties.

Losing my nerves after 2 hours of trying: [SCREENSHOT](http://imgur.com/ppTKdOg)

Comment: please post error why your gradle is not building

Comment: Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'   , but I am still missing all the files, as seen in screenshot